# Why is my AJAX request so slow?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

This AJAX request takes about a second to execute, and I wondered whether there was a way of speeding it up?

It's a button click event within the context of a Twitter-style follow/unfollow.

JS:

```
$.ajax
({
    type: "POST",
    url: "follow.php",
    data: {id: id, shop_name: shop_name},
    context: this,
    success: function(data)
    {
        if ($(this).html() == 'Add')
        {
            $(this).toggleClass('btn-primary');
            $(this).html('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span> Added');
        }

        else if ($(this).html() == '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span> Added')
        {
            $(this).toggleClass('btn-primary');
            $(this).html('Add');
        }
    }
});
```

PHP:

```
ini_set('display_startup_errors',1);
ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(-1);

include('connect.php');

$id = $_POST['id'];
$user_id = $id['id'];
$shop_name = mysqli_escape_string($con, $_POST['shop_name']);

$feed_id_query = "SELECT DISTINCT feed_id FROM shopaholic WHERE shop_name = '$shop_name'";
$feed_id = mysqli_query($con, $feed_id_query) or die(mysqli_error($con));
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($feed_id);
$feed_id = $row[0];

$query = "SELECT * FROM sh_subscriptions WHERE user_id = $user_id AND feed_id = $feed_id";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $query) or die(mysqli_error($con));

// check if row exists
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
{
    // row already exists, so check whether it is active
    $query2 = "SELECT * FROM sh_subscriptions WHERE user_id = $user_id AND feed_id = $feed_id AND active = 1";
    $result2 = mysqli_query($con, $query2) or die(mysqli_error($con));

    if (mysqli_num_rows($result2) > 0)
    {
        // row is active, so deactivate it
        $query3 = "UPDATE sh_subscriptions SET active = 0 WHERE user_id = $user_id AND feed_id = $feed_id";
        $result3 = mysqli_query($con, $query3) or die(mysqli_error($con));
    }

    else
    {
        // row is inactive, so activate it
        $query4 = "UPDATE sh_subscriptions SET active = 1 WHERE user_id = $user_id AND feed_id = $feed_id";
        $result4 = mysqli_query($con, $query4) or die(mysqli_error($con));
    }
}

else
{
    // row does not exist, so create it
    $query5 = "INSERT INTO sh_subscriptions (user_id, feed_id, active) VALUES ($user_id, $feed_id, 1)";
    $result5 = mysqli_query($con, $query5) or die(mysqli_error($con));
}
```

**UPDATE**

I'm checking the AJAX load times in the console. The vast majority of the time is spent 'waiting', which I presume is the PHP doing its work. It also loads more slowly the first time  (anything from 50ms slower at least) and then generally gets faster.

Comment: can you check the speed php?

Comment: Did you check WHICH part of the ajax call is slow? you're doing a lot of DB queries in the php code. maybe the actual http phase of the ajax call is taking up only 0.0000001 seconds, but the db stuff is taking up 0.9999999 seconds. If it's the php, then that's easy to speed up by optimizing the code. if it's the http layer, then the only thing you can do is switch to a higher speed/lower latency link.

Comment: @MarcB That was my first thought, but I don't know how to check it, though it's gotten slower as I've added more db stuff so I presume it's the PHP.

Comment: various dev tools can do basic timing analysis. e.g. "X seconds to send data", "Y seconds" to receive response, etc...

Comment: Check if you have proper INDEXEs on your tables in your DB

Comment: Is your `shop_name` indexed?  Is it a long list?  These may have an effect on performance.

Comment: Completely off topic, but you're vulnerable to SQL Injection. Fix here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18593728/mysqlibind-param-variables

Comment: Run the queries directly against the database and check the timing of each

Comment: e.g. one optimization: your "select to check active then change active" can be changed to a SINGLE update query: `update ... set active = 1 - active`. that'll toggle between 0/1 without having to do a select/fetch/test/change cycle.

Comment: You can use `EXPLAIN` before your query to see if it uses index.

Comment: You’re using MySQLi; use parametrized queries.

Comment: Anyways, first query query: why are you using `SELECT DISTINCT`? You’re only fetching one result.

Comment: @minitech That's a mistake, I meant to use "LIMIT 1"

Comment: As @minitech said, use parametrized queries to avoid SQL injections.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing you can try is to add "LIMIT 1" to both selects

```
$feed_id_query = "SELECT DISTINCT feed_id FROM shopaholic WHERE shop_name = '$shop_name' LIMIT 1";

$query = "SELECT * FROM sh_subscriptions WHERE user_id = $user_id AND feed_id = $feed_id LIMIT 1";
```

Since you neet only one result in each query

same here

```
$query2 = "SELECT * FROM sh_subscriptions WHERE user_id = $user_id AND feed_id = $feed_id AND active = 1 LIMIT 1";
```