# Could PHP use variable before defining them?

Tags: php

In php manual http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php

I see code like this:

```
$stmt->bind_param('sssd', $code, $language, $official, $percent);

$code = 'DEU';
$language = 'Bavarian';
$official = "F";
$percent = 11.2;

/* execute prepared statement */
$stmt->execute();
```

Comment: Yes it is possible. This has already been discussed  

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2961222/mysqli-declaring-variable-after-bind-param or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18593728/mysqlibind-param-variables?rq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `bind_param()` method stores *references to the values* of the `$code`, `$language`, `$official` and `$percent` variables. The references are stored inside the `$stmt` object.

When you then give the variables values the `$stmt` object already knows where to look for the values.

We can create a class, that does this, ourselves:

```
class Play {
    protected $reference;
    public function bind( & $variable) {
        $this->reference = &$variable;
    }
    public function show() {
        echo "{$this->reference}<br>\n";
    }
}
```

The `&` character is the reference operator. When you use it you get a reference to the value of another variable.

With this class we can create an object and have some fun:

```
$play = new Play;
$play->bind($string);

$string = 'Hello!';
$play->show();

$string = 'World!';
$play->show();
```

Answer (score -1):

No php can't use a variable before you write the declaration!

No language is obviously able to output a value, before it exists.